# Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm getting the following error when i try to debug a Spring boot with Gradle project in Eclipse

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]

Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

i've searched a lot, and most of the solutions came from something that is wrong in the application.properties file, but i can not figure what is wrong in mine

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dices?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: Try adding `&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` to `spring.datasource.url`. Without this directive the database (`dices` in your example) should be manually created first.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBG, the database is already created, anyway i've this without exit. In a  closer inspection into the error code i've realised this "Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  i'm googling a lite to see what i'm find

Comment: @RaulMagdalenaCatala where is the dependency in build.gradle? I want to see

Comment: Do you have spring starter for database in your dependency?

Comment: thanks @Faraz, yes "implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

Comment: I would suggest you try this: `@Bean @ConfigurationProperties(prefix= "spring.datasource" public javax.sql.DataSource datasource(){ return org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.create().build();}`

Comment: thanks @Faraz, where i have to add this code?

Comment: You would add this to a class that is annotated with `@Springbootapplication` or any class which is annotated with `@Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding **compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")** to your build.gradle and check again?

Comment: thanks @Gayathri, where i have to add this? into dependencies{}?

Comment: Yeah..Add then under dependencies.

Comment: Done,but no changes, still fails

Comment: Try adding spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect  .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with eclipse which was not downloading the dependencies. Gradle configuration files were ok